# Passing variables and metadata

Tags: clojure, scope

I wrote a short function for debugging:

```
(defn printvar
    "Print information about given variables in `name : value` pairs" 
    [& vars]
    (dorun (map #(println (name %) ":" (eval %)) vars)))
```

Then I tried to test it:

```
(defn -main [arg1 arg2]
    (def moustache true) (def answer 42) (def ocelots-are "awesome!")
    (printvar 'moustache 'answer 'ocelots-are)
    (printvar 'arg1 'arg2))
```

But ran into some really confusing behaviour:

```
$ lein repl
> (-main "one" "two")
# moustache : true
# answer : 42
# ocelots-are : awesome!
# CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: arg1 in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4449285856851838419.clj:1:1)

$ lein run "one" "two"
# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: moustache in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4557344131005109247.clj:1:113)
```

Experimenting a bit more, I discovered this:

```
(defn -main [arg1 arg2]
    (meta #'arg1))
# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: arg1 in this context, compiling:(dict_compress/core.clj:9:11)

(defn -main [arg1 arg2]
    (def arg1 arg1)
    (meta #'arg1))
# {:ns #<Namespace dict-compress.core>, :name arg1, :file dict_compress/core.clj, :column 2, :line 10}
```

Now I'm totally confused.

What exactly are you passing when you do `(f 'var)` and `(f var)`?

Why are there different behaviours when run from the REPL versus directly?

What's the difference between a received argument versus a defined variable?

How can I fix my code?

Am I going about debugging the wrong way?

Comment: Parameters are bound to their arguments in the environment of the function. They are not `var`s, just labels.

Comment: How do arguments differ from variables other than having no metadata? Is this normal, or is it just a Clojure thing?

Comment: Arguments are always values. That value can be of type `var` if you pass in things that are vars. For example if you called `(printvar #'arg1)` you would be passing in the var, rather than just its value. What won't work is `(printvar arg1)` because `printvar` gets passed the value of `arg1`, not the var itself.

Comment: And yes, you are doing debugging wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `printvar` the def'ed vars `moustache` `answer` and `ocelots-are` are correctly printed because `def` defines them as "globals".

Meaning there is a `moustache` var that the printvar function can "see".

Think about it this way, this works:

```
(def moustache 43)
(defn printvar [] 
   (println moustache)
(defn main [arg1]
    (printvar))
```

This doesn't work:

```
(defn printvar []
    (println arg1))
(defn main [arg1]
    (printvar))
```

Which is exactly what you're doing, passing the parameter *name* to eval does nothing for the parameter scope (`printvar` won't be able to see it).

A couple of issues with your code:

- You shouldn't be `defing` inside a function, local bindings are defined with `let`
- If you want to `eval` you need to consider scope of what you're evaling.

Comment: Right. So `moustache` is a variable, and `'moustache`is just text? Is there any way to pass a variable with metadata, or do I need to use a macro to solve this problem?

Comment: 'moustache is a symbol not text, if you wanna get the value from the symbol you can do `(var-get (ns-resolve *ns* 'moustache))` but still, you won't be able to "see" the `arg1` argument from the printvar function because it's not in scope.

Comment: if you change `printvar` into a macro it _may_ work since it would expand in scope

Comment: `#'moustache` is the standard way to access the var itself

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @Guillermo's comment, here is a macro that does the printing of any variable, locally or globally bound.

```
(defmacro printvar
  ([])
  ([v & more]
   `(let [v# ~v]
      (println '~v "=" v#)
      (when (seq '~more)
        (printvar ~@more)))))
```

With this you can try the sequence :

```
user> (def glob-var "foo")
#'user/glob-var
user> (defn -main [loc1 loc2]
        (printvar glob-var loc1 loc2))
#'user/-main
user> (-main "bar" 42)
glob-var = foo
loc1 = bar
loc2 = 42
nil
user>
```